# Describing a vector field

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Compare the vector field $G=(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$ along circle with fixed radius $r$ with the parametrization of a circle $\alpha = (r\cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$. Describe the field without solving for field lines. So if the radius is fixed we get $G=(\frac{-\sin \theta}{r}, \frac{\cos \theta}{r})$, what does this tell us about how the vector field is physically? A hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: the point on the circle is $P(r, \theta) = (r\cos{\theta}, r\sin{\theta})$. Try to calculate $P \cdot G$...

Comment: I think your calculation of $G$ is off by a factor of $r$.  (Note that the original $G$ has no units, but your calculation of it has units $1/r$.)  After that, just draw a circle, plot $G$ at a few points on the circle, and I think you'll see pretty clearly.  I think they are getting at how $G$ relates to the circle.

Comment: @Hugo do you mean inner/dot product? if so with my definition of $G$ you get $P \cdot G = 0$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @bob.sacamento  How is my $G$ off by a factor of $1/r$? I subbed in $x = r\cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$ and since $x^2+y^2=r^2$ you are left with that. Is that not the right way to do it? What do you mean by how $G$ relates to the circle? Like depending on the size of the radius, the strength of the field decreases/increases?

Comment: Since $P \cdot G = 0$ that means that the field lines of $G$ are orthogonal to the position vector from the origin to the circle $\alpha$, which means that G is tangent to the circle, and is travelling around it?

Comment: @Panphobia  Well, crap, I read it wrong.  You are right about the factor of $r$.  The rest of what I said still holds.  Your last comment is exactly right.

Comment: @bob.sacamento so what does that tell me about the strength of the field though? As the radius of the alpha increases and is greater than one, the field lines are weaker, and if they're less than one they increase?

Comment: @Panphobia  You seem to have gotten the idea, so I'll just say it more cleanly: The vectors point along circles and the magnitude of the vector decreases as $1/r$.  I think that's probably what you need to say.